# PHP : Add lowest value from duplicate records of array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to remove duplicate record which is highest value in array.

Array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [number] => 123
            [price] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [number] => 456
            [price] => 6
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [number] => 123
            [price] => 5
        )
)
```

Expected Result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [number] => 456
            [price] => 6
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [number] => 123
            [price] => 5
        )
)
```

number is duplicate field and after that need to compare price. Which will be lower that will be display. Rest of all should be removed.

What I tried :

```
$lowest = min($myArray);

$result = array_filter($myArray, function($value, $key) use ($lowest) {
    return $value === $lowest;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

How can i do that?

---

**UPDATE :**

@Daniel Dez solution is almost working. I used 3rd solution of him. But, It should be working like this.

For ex : number 123 is duplicate records now it's lowest price is 2. Then, it should be display rest of 123 number's array element remove.

**Array :**

```
$data = [
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "number" => 123,
        "price" => 2,
    ],
    [
        "id" => 2,
        "number" => 456,
        "price" => 6,
    ],
    [
        "id" => 3,
        "number" => 123,
        "price" => 5,
    ],
    [
        "id" => 4,
        "number" => 123,
        "price" => 11,
    ],
    [
        "id" => 5,
        "number" => 456,
        "price" => 5,
    ],
    [
        "id" => 6,
        "number" => 123,
        "price" => 5,
    ]
];
```

**Expected Output :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [number] => 123
            [price] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [number] => 456
            [price] => 5
        )

)
```

please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes. let me update it.

Comment: Please check my update question.

Comment: `$lowest = min($myArray)` makes no sense on such a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Yes. I think also. But, I have no solution that's why i added question here and need help.

Comment: @CBroe Can you please upload solution as answer?

Comment: I did not offer any solution yet; I am just pointing out what part of your attempt is plain obviously wrong to begin with. Assuming there can not only be one such duplicate in the input data set, but multiple, trying to determine _one_ single minimum value upfront, does not even make sense to begin with. You would need the specific minimum price value for each individual `number` value, for starters.

Comment: Can you add your expected output in your update?

Comment: Updated in quesetion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data:

```php
$numbers = array_unique(array_column($data, 'number'));

usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['price'] - $b['price'];
});
$result = [];
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        if ($item['number'] == $number) {
            break;
        }
    }

    $result[] = $item;
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answer. 3rd solution almost working proper. But, when id = 1 's price is 2 and id = 3's price is 5 then, in that case it's not working. it should be display 2.

Comment: Can you please check it and update that one?

Comment: I did it base on the number attribute

Comment: you can change it to price

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. Let me update in question.

Comment: Can you please check my updated question? Solution is near about can you please help me to solve it?

Comment: @AnkitaPatel Check it out